# Problem with toastr doesn't work sometimes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

sometimes the toastr in angular doesn't work until i reload the page and the html element toast-container doesn't exist in html until i reload:

import:

```
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr';
....
constructor(public toastr: ToastsManager){}
...
if (bDm === false) {
  this.toastr.warning('xxxx', 'yyyy');
  return false;
}
```

in app.modules

```
import { ToastModule, ToastOptions } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';
 ....
 imports: [
ToastModule.forRoot()
]
```

and in package.json i've got:

```
"ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
```

By the way the navigator i use is google chrome and no errors appairs in console.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution or at least it works for me: i have multimodule app, so in the module with this probleme i've added:

in xxxx.components.ts:

```
constructor(public vcr: ViewContainerRef,
          public toastr: ToastsManager) {
this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);
}
```